# How to remove the previous record , issue is when i select the city from the drop-down it will be concatenate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, api

I have a drop-down when i select the city from the option, weather data will be fetch through API, my issue is when i select option previous data cannot be remove. In this below screenshot 1st i selected city (KARACHI) api return the data on the screen accurately, when i select Islamabad only Islamabad weather data should be display. How can i overcome this issue.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select.select_city").change(function() {
    var selectedCountry = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
    // alert("You have selected the country - " + selectedCountry);
    // var cityy = "Lahore";
    $.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + selectedCountry + "&units=metric&APPID=d89208ad904d31a4402384ff1d4d1a2f",


      function(data) {
        console.log(data);

        var icon = "https://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + data.weather[0].icon + ".png";
        $('.icon').attr("src", icon);
        // console.log(icon);

        var temp = Math.round(data.main.temp);
        $('.temp').append(temp);

        var weather = data.weather[0].main;
        // console.log(weather);
        $('.weather').append(weather);

        var city = data.name;
        // console.log(city);
        $('.city').append(city);

      });
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="weather-container" style="background:#ccc;text-align:center">
  <img src="" alt="" class="icon">
  <p class="city"></p>
  <p class="weather" style="font-size: 22px;margin:0"></p>
  <p class="temp" style="font-size: 60px;margin:0;font-weight:bold"></p>
  <select name="" class="select_city" id="">
    <option value="Lahore">Lahore</option>
    <option value="Karachi">Karachi</option>
    <option value="Islamabad">Islamabad</option>
    <option value="Perth">Perth</option>
    <option value="Berlin">Berlin</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider writing a seperate function to get the data based on city and call it in dropdown's `change()` function, also you would want to use `.html()` instead of `.append()`:

```js
function getData(city) {
  $.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + city + "&units=metric&APPID=d89208ad904d31a4402384ff1d4d1a2f",

    function(data) {
      //console.log(data);

      var icon = "https://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + data.weather[0].icon + ".png";
      $('.icon').attr("src", icon);

      var temp = Math.round(data.main.temp);
      $('.temp').html(temp);

      var weather = data.weather[0].main;
      $('.weather').html(weather);

      var city = data.name;
      $('.city').html(city);
    }
  );
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  getData("Lahore");
  $("select.select_city").change(function() {
    var selectedCountry = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
    //alert("You have selected the country - " + selectedCountry);
    getData(selectedCountry)
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="weather-container" style="background:#ccc;text-align:center">
  <img src="" alt="" class="icon">
  <p class="city"></p>
  <p class="weather" style="font-size: 22px;margin:0"></p>
  <p class="temp" style="font-size: 60px;margin:0;font-weight:bold"></p>
  <select name="" class="select_city" id="">
    <option value="Lahore">Lahore</option>
    <option value="Karachi">Karachi</option>
    <option value="Islamabad">Islamabad</option>
    <option value="Perth">Perth</option>
    <option value="Berlin">Berlin</option>
  </select>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```